# Typescript Cypress error when getting variable as string

Tags: typescript, cypress

I'm migrating to using Typescript with Cypress but have an issue type casting aliases. I'm expecting a `string` but typescript is expecting `JQuery<HTMLElement>`.

Example:

```js
cy.wrap("a string").as("myString")

cy.get("@myString").then( myString => {
   console.log(typeof myString) // => "string"
})
```

I checked the typescript definitions for `cy.get` and found:

```js
get<E extends Node = HTMLElement>(selector: string, options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable & Withinable & Shadow>): Chainable<JQuery<E>>
// AND
get<E extends Node = HTMLElement>(selector: string, options?: Partial<Loggable & Timeoutable & Withinable & Shadow>): Chainable<JQuery<E>>
```

At the moment, I'm getting the following error:

```
Argument of type '(myString: string) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: ObjectLike, currentSubject: JQuery<HTMLElement>) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'myString' and 'currentSubject' are incompatible.
        Type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

How can I fix this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the output in the following manner:

```js
cy.get<string>("@myString").then( myString => {
   // Do something here
})
```